# Ajax doesn't send all of data

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have the problem with my request. Look at this code

```
logInWithFacebook = function() {
FB.login(function(response) {
  if (response.authResponse) {
     FB.api('/me', {fields: 'name,email,location,picture'},function(userInfo) {

         FB.api('/me/picture?type=normal', function (response) {
            userInfo.photo = response.data.url; // what's wrong with that?
          });

          if(userInfo.location)
          {
            var location = userInfo.location.name.split(",");
            userInfo.location = location[0];
          }

        $.ajax({
            data:userInfo,
            type:"POST",
            url:"/login/facebook-loginexecute",
            dataType: "json",
            beforeSend: function() {
            console.log(userInfo); // everything is showing
            },
            success: function(result) {

            }
        });         
    });
  } 
},{scope: 'public_profile,email,user_location'});
return false;
```

};

So, after the send data (in this case "userinfo") through ajax, PHP function print_r - return everything without element's $_POST - photo. I don't know why?
'

Comment: FB api is asynchronous....you can't send data that hasn't been received yet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess is that `FB.api` call is asynchronous, so you fire it in the background and then fire your own ajax call before FB.api success callback is executed.

Move your ajax call inside of the FB.api callback:

```
logInWithFacebook = function() {
    FB.login(function(response) {
        if (response.authResponse) {
            FB.api('/me', {
                fields: 'name,email,location,picture'
            }, function(userInfo) {

                FB.api('/me/picture?type=normal', function(response) {
                    userInfo.photo = response.data.url; // what's wrong with that?

                    if (userInfo.location) {
                        var location = userInfo.location.name.split(",");
                        userInfo.location = location[0];
                    }

                    $.ajax({
                        data: userInfo,
                        type: "POST",
                        url: "/login/facebook-loginexecute",
                        dataType: "json",
                        beforeSend: function() {
                            console.log(userInfo); // everything is showing
                        },
                        success: function(result) {

                        }
                    });

                });

            });
        }
    }, {
        scope: 'public_profile,email,user_location'
    });
    return false;
};
```

As to why is it showing in the console, the console probably maintains a reference to the object, and by the time you look at it, the initial request has been completed.

Comment: Maksim! Thank you very much for your help! Now, everything works perfectly! I know about asynchronous requests but if inside the function beforeSend I had this data, I thought that exactly everything will send without troubles. Once again, thank you for your explain!

Comment: No worries, glad to help!